# How to reset lost admin password in Magento 2?

Tags: admin, magento2, password-recovery

I tried to reset the admin password via Phpmyadmin in admin_user table but this doesn't seems to work. Also on chrome I am getting "This webpage has a redirect loop" error when loading admin page.

Comment: Regarding redirects, make sure that if you have xdebug enabled, then there is `xdebug.max_nesting_level=200` in your php.ini. If it is not set, it is possible that you see admin login page (because nesting level is less than default 100 on that page), but when you enter credentials and try to login, dashboard cannot be rendered (nesting level is more than default 100 there). Also make sure to use some virtual host, not "localhost", to avoid issues with cookies.

Comment: Dashboard icons / style were not loaded / rendered properly will this be due to xdebug ? Can you share how to setup xdebug on php.ini properly

Comment: Just add `xdebug.max_nesting_level=200` to your php.ini config if you have XDebug enabled.

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2175

Comment: this answer should help http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/137562/27907 and to generate the hashed password you can use http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can use Magento CLI to create new admin user with the following command, then you can go and change password of your original user.

Execute this from the root of your magento installation:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="123123q" --admin-email="admin@example.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin"
```

Comment: No other way without CLI? I tried to do that by installing Magerun on my machine (I am newbie to CLI). My command is like below, '<path_to_magento>php bin/magento admin:user:create [--admin-user="dave"] [--admin-password="admin123"] [--admin-email="admin1@localhost.com"] [--admin-firstname="dave"] [--admin-lastname="maritus"]'

Comment: Path to magento should go before "bin/magento", not before php. Also remove square brackets from actual command.

Comment: Admin user created successfully, I used the details created to login dashboard but it doesn't works, stay on the same login page.

Comment: This is another problem, probably for separate question. Have you checked my comment about xdebug and localhost above? Also your session storage may be not writable and cause this.

Comment: only god knows why they put square brackets there...

Comment: @MagenX - Square brackets are a conventional way for help messages of a command to tell you that those arguments are _optional_. It's pretty standard [actually](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html).

Comment: Added additional comments explaining how to overcome Exception message - https://www.maxpronko.com/blog/how-to-create-admin-user-in-magento-2-via-command-line

Comment: Does this work in Magento 2.1.7? The `bin/magento` directory is missing. That means there is no _magento_ directory in the _bin_ directory. There is just a "magento" _file_ there instead.

Comment: Be sure to check the "lock_expires" fields also if you've tried multiple wrong passwords...

Comment: @AlexPaliarush, This will create new user, how can we reset the password for existing user?

Comment: It seems that this command also updates the data for the admin-user in question.

Answer (score 34):

Run below query to direct database.

An example is for reset password for **admin** user.

> UPDATE admin_user SET `password` = SHA2('**NewPassword**', 256) WHERE `username`='**admin**';

**NewPassword**: Replace it with your password.

I hope it will work for you. Let me know if you any difficulty.

Comment: FYI; the CONCAT and salt is not needed. v. 2.1.7

Comment: Didn't work for Magento 2.3, needs salt, etc.

Comment: also, beware "lock_expires" field if you've repeated tried the same wrong password...

Answer (score 24):

Run the following SQL queries to reset the admin password:

```
SET @salt = MD5(UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2(CONCAT(@salt, 'MyNewPassword'), 256), ':', @salt, ':1') WHERE username = 'admin';
```

Comment: Was the only way I could get around the password requirements in Magento 2.3, to be able to set a simple admin password for development. `n98-magerun2` 3.0.4 didn't allow one to avoid the admin password requirements.

Comment: Worked in Magento 2.2.5, plus setting "lock_expires" to NULL

Comment: Worked in Magento 2.3.3, many thanks

Comment: Still works on 2.3.4. Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

There is a very nice tool out there called [N98-Magerun](https://files.magerun.net/)

Basically, you directly download it to the root of your Magento project

```
wget https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun2.phar
```

Next set executable permissions (for UNIX users only)

```
chmod +x ./n98-magerun2.phar
```

Now when you run

```
php n98-magerun2.phar
```

You will get a list of all available commands offered by the tool.

Now for resetting a forgotten admin user password first we need to get the username of the admin user, to get that we can run

```
php n98-magerun2.phar admin:user:list
```

This will provide you a list all the available admin user, the output will look something like

```
+----+-----------------+-------------------------------+--------+
| id | username        | email                         | status |
+----+-----------------+-------------------------------+--------+
| 1  | admin           | admin@example.com             | active |
| 2  | nextadmin       | nextadmin@example.com         | active |
+----+-----------------+-------------------------------+--------+
```

Now to reset the password we do

```
php n98-magerun2.phar admin:user:change-password
```

You will be prompted for the username of the admin user and new password for that user.

```
Username:admin
Password:123456
Password successfully changed
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Couldn't get this to run in my Bitnami test server - SQL was the only way to go for me.

Answer (score 15):

There should be no equal signs or square brackets like this:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user mys_username --admin-password mypass123 --admin-email my@email.com --admin-firstname john --admin-lastname cage
```

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me

Answer (score 4):

I hate remember long string bin/magento ...

Here is solution for anyone like touching:

put this code in pub/index.php

```
\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get("\Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor")->getHash("yourpass");
```

Look at the footer of anypage:
[image]

Copy that code and go to phpmyadmin:

```
update admin_user set password = '<code above>' where username='admin';
```

BTW. This is reset password question if you use admin:user:create it do reset or create but Uhm... Not exactly.

Comment: This would not really be safe to do in a publicly open website... You could also download [n98-magerun2](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2) and run `n98-magerun2.phar dev:console` and execute the code there: `$di->get("\Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor")->getHash("yourpass");` or just use `n98-magerun2.phar admin:user:change-password`

Answer (score 3):

From Magento 2.3 you can use like following

```
UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2('[salt]NewPassword', 256), ':[salt]:1') WHERE username = 'admin';
```

And for salt you can get it from the `app/etc/env.php`

```
'crypt' => [
    'key' => 'f6fcdcc54d85d8a2f2a87a2ae0a062e9'
],
```

**OR**

If you are emails are working use the forget password option in the admin login screen

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Referring to answer of Alex it works with a little modification. You have to navigate into the folder of M2 install, then run the code below:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --admin-email=admin@magento.tld --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin
```

You don't need `/` before the `bin` folder, but you need `php` command before the whole "sentence".

The pass generation worked for me, but the admin page was'nt logged me in:/

Answer (score 0):

Just open your database access and call the following query:

```
UPDATE admin_user
SET password = CONCAT(SHA2('yournewpassword', 256), ':xxxxxxx:1')
WHERE username = 'yourusername';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this command in terminal**

php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin-password" --admin-email="account@example.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin"

Answer (score -1):

```
 1. login to magento 2 admin.
 2. Go to system > All Users.
 3. Select your User
 4. reset password from 'User Info' > 'Account Information'
```

Comment: I have edited my question. what If we do when lost a password.