# Unable to get to the System Configuration in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, system-configuration

Fresh install of both community and enterprise Magento 2. I am trying to get to the System configuration but i am seeing this instead.
[image]

What do I need to do?
If I put in my credentials from magento.com I get this page:
[image]

I do see some posts online that do show a page similar to the Engerprise 1.14 System->Configuration so I know it exists, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your admin user is assigned to a role, which has limited access to admin resources (those which define ACL and are usually configured per admin user role). Try to [create new admin user via CLI](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/90933/697).

Comment: FYI - Maybe this is a bug in the webpage setup but this is what I got out of the box.  Let me try the CLI version and I will let you know.

Comment: yes, that appears to be the case.  I created a new user via CLI and its working as expected.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: this doesn't help in Magento 2.0.7