# Invalid User Name or Password

Tags: login

I have been unable to access my website this morning. Getting this message - Invalid User Name or Password. I have changed my password but it seems to be the username that's the issue. Can anyone help me?

Comment: are you asking about admin?

Comment: Yes I am Denish

Comment: nice question +1 for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset lost admin password in Magento 2?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90922/how-to-reset-lost-admin-password-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 3):

If you are having troubles and want to reset it to a different password, just run at your sql database:

get your username with query

```
SELECT * FROM admin_user;
```

and than change password using query

```
UPDATE admin_user SET password=CONCAT(MD5('qXpassword'), ':qX') WHERE username='admin';
```

if password = "admin1234" than define query like

```
 UPDATE admin_user SET password=CONCAT(MD5('qXadmin1234'), ':qX') WHERE username='admin';
```

**note:- check your username**

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: if this answer solve your query than accept and +1 this will help to other to solve future query to other buddies.