# Unable to Login to Magento 2.4 Admin Page in localhost

Tags: magento2, cms, admin-panel

As the title states, I am unable to log in to the default admin user in Magento 2.4 after installation using composer.
I have tried changing the password through PHPMyAdmin using the following command:

`UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxYourNewPassword', 256), ':xxxxxxx:1') WHERE username = 'admin';`

as well as the following command:

`UPDATE admin_user SET password=CONCAT(MD5('qXpassword'), ':qX') WHERE username='admin';`

I have also tried creating a new admin user through this command line:

`php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user='new-admin' --admin-password='!admin123!' --admin-email='info@domain.com' --admin-firstname='Jon' --admin-lastname='Doe'`

But I get the following error message nonetheless:

> The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later.

I also tried to "unlock" the users using:

`php bin/magento admin:user:unlock adminuser`

Which printed

> The user account "admin1" has been unlocked

But had no notable effect otherwise.

I have also tried clearing my browser cache and multiple browsers.
`Vivalid` `Chrome` `Edge` `Firefox`

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks in advance.
Have a great day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the following SQL queries for reset your admin password

```
SET @salt = MD5(UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2(CONCAT(@salt, '!admin123!'), 256), ':', @salt, ':1'), is_active = 1  WHERE username = 'admin';
```

Try with

> username : admin

> Password : !admin123!

Comment: Hey thanks, that worked. But can you explain what the thought behind this command is so I can better understand it?

Comment: previous magento version use sh2, encrypted mechanisam for change password.

Comment: you will get better idea from 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137555/magento-2-how-to-reset-customer-password-from-database

Comment: Thanks again, I'll definitely take a look

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new admin user and then try to log in with new user details

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin@123 --admin-email=test@example.com --admin-firstname=Admin --admin-lastname=Admin
```