# Forgot admin password for admin panel

Tags: magento2, password, password-recovery

My client forgot admin password.

We use magento 2.1

How can change password in database?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this: https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_reset_admin_password_in_magento/

```
UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxxNewPassword', 256), ':xxxxxxxx:1') WHERE username = 'ADMINUSERNAME';
```

Or you can follow this to create new admin user and when you logged in you can edit the old account 
[How to reset lost admin password in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90922/how-to-reset-lost-admin-password-in-magento-2)

Comment: Also, check the `lock_expires` field as well...

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 you can use this command to set admin password

```
/bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="Abc@123456" --admin-email="test@example.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin"
```