# Magento 2:- "Forgot your password?" issue from admin side

Tags: magento2, email, password

I try to change admin password by Forgot your password link but I did not get any email for Forgot password.

Comment: <path_to_magento>/bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="123123q" --admin-email="admin@example.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin"

Comment: @Brijitsinh I know this solution but I want forgot email to reset the password so it is easy for a nontechnical person.

Comment: after login check email setting Store>>setting>>configuration>>Admin>>Admin User Emails

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #1**

This answer is taken from https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/141612/62052

> UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxxNewPassword', 256), ':xxxxxxxx:1') WHERE username = 'admin';

**Solution #2**

This answer is taken from https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/90933/62052

```
path_to_magento/bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="123123q" --admin-email="admin@example.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin"
```

Comment: I know this solution, but I want to forget email to reset the password so it is easy for a non technical person.

Comment: do you have smtp configured?

Comment: Remember that the retrieve password only works if an account is associated with the email address.

Comment: I have not SMTP configured. And I try with an email address which I have assigned to my user.

Comment: Again, you need to configure SMTP inorder to send mails

Comment: My Project is live so, I did not need SMTP.

Comment: I'm sorry, I failed you. In the future, please be more specific when writing your question.

Answer (score 0):

after login check email setting

```
Store>>setting>>configuration>>Admin>>Admin User Emails
```

Comment: I can see 3 option over there and all of them set as default so now what I have to do?

Comment: if your project on localhost you need smtp Otherwise do not change