# reset password for magento2 admin panel

Tags: magento2

i have tried to reset password from mysql cli.   myqueri is for that 
UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2('12345678admin', 256), ':12345678:1') WHERE username = '*****'

Comment: after update password i am not able to login admin backend in magento2

Comment: Please respond to the comments in the right place :))

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: SQL query

**NewPassword** with the new password, and replace both occurrences of xxxxxxxx with any random character sequence:

```
UPDATE admin_user SET `password` = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxxNewPassword', 256), ':xxxxxxxx:1') WHERE `username` = 'admin';
```

reference link: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/optimization-and-configuration/magento1/resetting-the-magento-administrator-password

Step 2:

You can use Magento CLI to create new admin user with the following command, then you can go and change password of your original user.

```
<path_to_magento>/bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="123123q" --admin-email="admin@example.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin"
```

reference link: [How to reset lost admin password in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90922/how-to-reset-lost-admin-password-in-magento-2)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: +1 upvoted for the explanation in the step 1. I was confused about xxxxxx.. and the solution 1 worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new user if you don't remember your password

`php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="your_name" --admin-password="your_pass" --admin-email="your_email" --admin-firstname="first_name" --admin-lastname="last_name"`

**Thanks**

Comment: Why you thanked? :)

Answer (score 0):

**Magento 2 does not support reset password via command line cli. However, we can create a new admin account by cli, then use the new account to reset the old one.**
or
update by phpmyadmin database direct query:

```
UPDATE admin_user SET `password` = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxxNewPassword', 256), ':xxxxxxxx:1') WHERE `username` = 'admin';
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento supports out of the box password change via CLI.
You should use the command to create an admin user, but enter details of existing user
`bin/magento admin:user:create`

Then you should enter a new admin password. Pay attention. The email you enter should be the same as in the database, otherwise, you'll catch an exception.

Answer (score -1):

Magento 2 doesn't support this out of the box. You can however download [n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2) for magento 2.

Once installed, you will have a few new Magento CLI commands. One of these new commands will let you change the password for your admin user.

`n98-magerun2.phar admin:user:change-password username password`